# How to close modal when click outside Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to close the modal when it's clicked outside. I have tried to loop through modals but can't get them to set its display to none.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="projects">
            <div data-modal="modal1">
                <div>
                      <p>Coffee</p>
                </div>
                <img src="img/coffee.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div data-modal="modal2">
                <div>
                       <p>Tea</p>
                </div>
                <img src="img/tea.png" alt="">
            </div>
      </div>

<div class="project-card" id="modal1">
            <button class="close">X</button>
        <div class="overlay">
            <img src="img/coffee.png" alt="">
        </div>
</div>
        
<div class="project-card" id="modal2">
            <button class="close">X</button>
        <div class="overlay">
            <img src="img/tea.png" alt="">
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code to open modals.

```
const coffeeGrounds = document.querySelectorAll('.projects > div[data-modal^=modal]');
for (var i = 0; i < coffeeGrounds.length; i++) {
    coffeeGrounds[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var x = this.getAttribute('data-modal');
        var a = document.getElementById(x);
        a.setAttribute('style','display:block');
       
    });
}
```

Here is my code, when clicked outside to close the modal:

```
window.addEventListener('click',function(){
    
   for(var i = 0; i<coffeeGrounds.length; i++){
         var x = coffeeGrounds[i].getAttribute('data-modal');
             var a = document.getElementById(x);
                console.log(a);
                if(a.style.display === 'block'){
                      a.setAttribute('style','display:none');
                 }
             }
        });
```

Over here by setting the modal display to none. It's holding back to display the modal also.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/zaidik/pen/bGwpzbE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click outside of the modal window you should not have the modal window in you event propagation array

In other words take advantage of event.path property

Working example (based on the provided fiddle)

```
  window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const allModals = document.querySelectorAll('.project-card');
  if (!e.path.some(x => x.className && x.className.includes('project-card'))) {
    allModals.forEach(x => x.style.display = 'none');
  }
}, true)
```

Working fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/7pzs1042/

Comment: Can you apply this to my example for some reason I cannot access path.find on the event

Comment: if you create a fiddle (example demo online), then I might have a look

Comment: thank you so much. Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/zaidik/pen/bGwpzbE

Comment: Modals open and closes. Also, I have commented out the clicked outside feature.

Comment: @ZaidKhan check the code again, copy and paste it into your codepen and it should work

Comment: Thanks a lot It's working flawlessly now. event.path is something new to me I will surely dig more into this.

Comment: @ZaidKhan, there are even simpler ways of doing it but it came to my mind first so. I decided to solve it with it.

Comment: As long as it's working I have no problem with it. But will surely look into this if I can make this work another way. Again Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to the accepted answer, by Eugensunic

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const allModals = document.querySelectorAll('.project-card');
  
//e.path is deprecated
// use instead e.composedPath() like this: 
  let paths = e.composedPath()
if (!paths.some(x => x.className && x.className.includes('project-card'))) {
    allModals.forEach(x => x.style.display = 'none');
  }
}, true)
```